# Eclipse Android SDK performance tweaks

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having some performance issues while developing Android apks. My machine is an AMD Quad Core 3Ghz clock with 4gigs of memory running Windows XP 32bits, I can't use 64bits because  other tools I have installed. Even with this hardware, performance is really slow, mainly when I do step-by-step debugging (sorry, I'm a firmware engineer used to debug that way, I've tried with LOG.d but didn't like it).

Is there any kind of black magic trick to improve Eclipse for Android developers??

Comment: Eclipse does suck :) (guess being written in Java and all) but most Android developers I know stick to this because its the easiest to setup for Android development and is cross platform. However Android can be setup with another IDE (may be more work though). And I don't know if this can be optimized (try checking on the eclipse site though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't we wish. You have a common problem. For me, I switched from windows to Ubuntu 11.04 and I have been running smooth. The emulator, however, has always been a steaming pile.